# Почему не правильно работает перегрузка operator!=

Tags: c++

Document.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using std::list;
using std::istream;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

typedef std::vector<char> Line;

class Text_Iterator //итератор для класса Document (состоит из 2-х членов)
{
    list<Line>::iterator itLine; //строка документа
    Line::iterator pos;          //позиция в строке

public:
    Text_Iterator(list<Line>::iterator ll, Line::iterator pp)
    {
        itLine = ll; pos = pp;
    }
    Text_Iterator& operator++()
    {
        //если pos на конце строки документа, переходим на начало следующей, иначе на след. символ pos
        if (++pos == itLine->end())
        {
            ++itLine; pos = itLine->begin();
        }
        else ++pos;

        return *this;
    };
    Text_Iterator& operator--()
    {
        //если pos в начале строки, то становимся на конец пред. строки, иначе --pos
        if (pos == (itLine->begin()))
        {
            itLine--; pos = --(itLine->end());
        }
        else --pos;

        return *this;
    };

    char& operator*() { return *pos; }

    bool operator==(const Text_Iterator& arg) const { return (arg.pos == pos); }
    bool operator!=(const Text_Iterator& arg) const { return !(*this == arg); } //this не заполнен, почему?

};
//класс текстового документа
struct Document  {

    list<Line> List;    
    Document() { List.push_back(Line()); }

    Text_Iterator begin() { return Text_Iterator(List.begin(), List.begin()->begin());
                          }
    Text_Iterator end() {

        list<Line>::iterator end = List.end();
        end--;
        Line::iterator end_pos = end->end();
        end_pos--;

        return Text_Iterator(end, end_pos);
                        }
//оператор ввода документа  
friend istream& operator >> (istream& is, Document& doc)
    {
        char input;
        int i(1);
        while (is.get(input))
        {
            cout << "#" << i++ << ":" << input << "\n";
            doc.List.back().push_back(input);
            if (input == '\n') //получили символ конца
                doc.List.push_back(Line());
        }   

        doc.List.back().push_back('\n');//добавляем чтобы применять back()

        return is;
    }

};
```

Когда обхожу контейнер в цикле не корректно проходит !=. Получею assert (MSVS 2015)
Main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Document txt;
    cin >> txt;
    for (Text_Iterator it = txt.begin(); it != txt.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it;
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, ошибка здесь:

```
if (++pos == itLine->end())
{
    ++itLine; pos = itLine->begin();
}
else ++pos;
```

Вы инкрементируете `pos` дважды, в результате этого `pos` может после второго увеличения стать равным `itLine->end()`.

Попробуйте просто

```
if (++pos == itLine->end())
{
    ++itLine; pos = itLine->begin();
}
// без else
```

Answer (score 2):

Для начала укажу на опечатку. В функции

```
Text_Iterator& operator++()
{
    //если pos на конце строки документа, переходим на начало следующей, иначе на след. символ pos
    if (++pos == itLine->end())
    {
        ++itLine; pos = itLine->begin();
    }
    else ++pos;

    return *this;
};
```

два раза увеличивается член класса `pos` если условие в выражении `if` не равно истине.

Кроме того вы сравниваете только один член данных `pos` класса `Text_Iterator`

```
bool operator==(const Text_Iterator& arg) const { return (arg.pos == pos); }
```

вместо двух: `pos` и `itLine`.

Кроме того в функции `end`, в которой я не нашел закрывающуюся фигурную скобку

```
Text_Iterator end() {

    list<Line>::iterator end = List.end();
    end--;
    Line::iterator end_pos = end->end();
    end_pos--;

    return Text_Iterator(end, end_pos);
} // <===
```

переменная `end_pos` не должна уменьшаться. То есть предложение

```
    end_pos--;
```

следует удалить.

Comment: Да, насчет первых замечаний верно.

Comment: если не уменьшать end_pos, то pos будет же указывать на несуществуюший символ...разве не так?

Comment: @СергейSer Итератор, возвращаемый функцией end должен указывать за последний элемент последовательности. Иначе ваша программа будет иметь неопределенное поведение. Вы создаете объект класса Document, занося в него пустой вектор. Уменьшение итератора для пустого вектора ведет к неопределенному поведению программы.

Comment: И все таки оставил так

Comment: for (Text_Iterator it = doc.begin(); it != doc.end(); ++it)
  os << *it;

Comment: П.С. Не удобно здесь комментировать.
 В итоге operator++ приводил к ошибке потому что было обращение вида itLine->begin(), к пустому вектору, что в С++

Comment: не допустимо...

Answer (score 0):

В итоге я решил оставить семантику метода Document.end(), чтобы он указывал на последний символ в контейнере. В таком случае, его нужно всегда заполнять по-умолчанию, но это не хорошее решение...

Но цикл (ниже), который вроде выглядит нормально, тогда проходит без выхода итератора за его пределы.

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, Document& doc)
{
    for (Text_Iterator it = doc.begin(); it != doc.end(); ++it)
    os << *it;
    return os;
}
```